# ANTLR matching chars when other chars required first?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

See the grammar below. When I try to parse:

```
String s = "UNH+message refere+APERAK:D:97A:UN\n";
```

I get the following error:

```
line 1:34 mismatched character '\n' expecting 'H'
line 2:0 missing RDEL at '<EOF>'
```

Which doesn't make sense to me since it seems to be looking for UNH before encountering a \n, which would not follow the 'file' rule.

```
    grammar Aperak;

    options {
      language = Java;
    }

    @header { package test.fixed.aperak; }
    @lexer::header { package test.fixed.aperak; }

    file returns [String result]: 'UNH' unh01 unh02 RDEL { $result = $unh01.text + " -- " + $unh02.text; };

    unh01 : FDEL optField;
    unh02 : FDEL unh02x1 unh02x2 unh02x3 unh02x4 (unh02x5)?;
    unh02x1 : optField;
    unh02x2 : SDEL optField;
    unh02x3 : SDEL optField;
    unh02x4 : SDEL optField;
    unh02x5 : SDEL optField;

    optField : AN*;

    RDEL : '\n';
    SDEL : ':';
    FDEL : '+';

    AN : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | ' ';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lexer really looks like this:

```
UNH  : 'UNH';
RDEL : '\n';
SDEL : ':';
FDEL : '+';
AN   : 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | ' ';
```

The literal `'UNH'` in your `file` rule becomes a lexer rule placed above all other lexer rules.

When the lexer now stumbles upon `"UN"` followed by something other than `"H"`, it produces an error because the lexer has nowhere to backtrack to. If your `AN` rule had matched more than a single character, the lexer could follow that rule, but since it only matches a single character, the lexer will not backtrack from `"UN"`.

As dasblinkenlight already suggested is correct: `AN` should match 1 or more characters and `optField` can then match an optional `AN`. The other part of his (or her) answer is not quite correct though: hence my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think ANTLR gets genuinely confused with two overlapping rules that cover the `UNH` input:

- A single token `UNH`, or
- A sequence of three tokens of type `AN`, with texts of `"U"`, `"N"`, and `"H"`

I think you should modify your `optField` and `AN` rules to move the `*` into the lexer, like this:

```
optField : AN?;

AN : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | ' ')+;
```

Comment: Your fix is correct, but the answer is not entirely correct: the lexer does not get confused because of the three tokens: these tokens (`"U"`, `"N"`, `"H"`) will not be created. After trying to create an `UNH` token from input like `"UNx"` (where `"x"` is anything other than `"H"`), the lexer has nowhere to backtrack to since `AN` matches a single character.

Comment: @BartKiers I did not say the three tokens *would* be created, only that there is a rule that *could* be used to interpret the string `UNH` as a sequence of three tokens. To me, "the lexer has nowhere to backtrack" is a smart way of saying "the lexer gets confused" :)

Comment: You said: *"A sequence of three tokens of type `AN`, with texts of `"U"`, `"N"`, and `"H"`"*... Perhaps you meant it as I just said it, but the wording suggests what I commented earlier.

Comment: @BartKiers The wording does not suggest any of that, unless you take it out of context: "A single token UNH, *or* a sequence of three tokens of type AN, with texts of `"U"`, `"N"`, and `"H"`" says what it says, not that "`"U"`, `"N"`, `"H"`) will be created".

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase: "but the wording **to me** suggests what I commented earlier."